# Where is the product gallery stored in the database?

Tags: magento-1.9, gallery

I can't to set it from admin.
[image]
 And I must set it by SQL query. So how I can do it? Or where stored url from picture in database? Picture in media already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table in database here in 'value' column image path is saved

For writing custom query for this table you need to use core_read and core_write connection to update the table.

For Read Connection :

```
$readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `attribute_id`=89";
    $rows       = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
```

For write connection :

```
$writeConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $sql        = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` SET value = 'test.jpeg' WHERE `attribute_id`=89";
        $rows       = $writeConnection->query($sql);
```